# How can I send emails via PHP on a VPS with no smtp / mail server?

Tags: php, email, vps

I'm moving a few sites from a full managed cPanel VPS to a cheaper VPS that basically has nothing (runs ubuntu 12.04).

The PHP scripts that I have send email via the `mail()` function.

I'd rather avoid installing any mail server stuff onto the VPS. I'm open to paid mail services or other methods. I'm not even sure what this would be called so finding it hard to find solutions.

Comment: Isn't `sendmail` a single executable?

Comment: On most VPS's `sendmail` is configured by default. Try to following from the command line: `echo test | sendmail -v your@address.com`.

Comment: nice tip @PeeHaa but I don't have it: ```The program 'sendmail' can be found in the following packages:
 * exim4-daemon-heavy
 * exim4-daemon-light
 * postfix
 * citadel-mta
 * courier-mta
 * dma
 * esmtp-run
 * lsb-invalid-mta
 * masqmail
 * msmtp-mta
 * nullmailer
 * qmail-run
 * sendmail-bin
 * ssmtp
 * xmail
Try: apt-get install <selected package>```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer to send emails using an authenticated SMTP server, like Gmail.

Comment: so I don't actually need to have a real email account for that domain? i.e. I don't need to do anything with MX records for that domain?

Comment: Yes, you only need to have an Gmail account, for instance. So you configure PHPMailer or SwiftMailer to use that account to send emails (i'd recommend SwiftMailer).

Comment: You'll need to configure the gmail account to allow for remote SMTP access as well.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I've forgot this.

Comment: Basically you need a username and password to any mail server with SMTP.

Comment: @fonini - just curious - why do you recommend Swiftmailer over PHPmailer? Both seem to be maintained regularly

Comment: @JM4 Because I like it. I've been using it in the Symfony Framework.

Comment: @fonini - you should try filet mignon if you haven't before. Want to know why? Because I like it.

Comment: @JM4 Man, I've got some SMTP problems on a server about a year ago using PHPMailer. Just replaced it with SwiftMailer and it worked like a charm. I've been using it since them. Happy?

Comment: haha - just giving you a hard time. Good enough for me. Was just curious if you knew of any actual benefits (memory usage, speed, better code, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use free smtp email sending classes such as [phpmailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.smtp.php?r=7) to send emails from your server using some other smtp providers.

[Mandril](http://mandrill.com/) is one of the best cheap SMTP providers available in the net. They allow 12000 emails per month for free.